# MS Graph adding subscription returns ExtensionError and ServiceUnavailable

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, exchange-server

When trying to create a subscription on some of my customers calendars using MS Graph (https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions), I get this error for a few users

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ExtensionError",
    "message": "Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: ServiceUnavailable; Reason: Target resource 'xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxx' hosted on database 'xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxx' is currently on backend 'Unknown']",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2020-11-27T00:12:53",
      "request-id": "xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxx",
      "client-request-id": "xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxx"
    }
  }
}
```

The documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/errors suggests that ExtensionError means that the users calendar is on an on premises Exchange Server, but I am able to read and write the events of the users calendar, so I don't think this is the case. Any other suggestions?

Comment: When you say that you can able to read/write the events of the users calendar, i believe you do it programmatically using Graph API, right?

Comment: Share the requestid, timestamp

Comment: Yes, it is through the Graph API. I just observed the problem again at this time 2020-11-27T10:30:11, and the request id is 55b227b8-65da-4f94-a0fa-01ba63537c7b

Comment: Cool. Also have you checked the ApplicationAccessPolicy or configured it correctly? If not, it might be causing this as well. Here's the doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access

Comment: Thanks for helping. If I understand you correctly, your suggestion is that the users Outlook account administrator has changed the ApplicationAccessPolicy so that my application doesn't have the required permissions? How can I check if this is the case? I am pretty sure that my application requires the correct permissions, since this application works fine for many of our users.

Comment: You may need to check with your administrator to see whether they implemented this policy or not

Comment: I don't think I understand your suggestion @Dev. I use MS OpenId connect and MS Graph to get access to the users calendar. When making the OpenId connect I set the scopes to openid, offline_access, Calendars.ReadWrite, Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared and User.Read. As far as I can see these scopes should be enough to allow me to subscribe to notifications from the users calendar. If the users administrator have set some access policy that doesn't allow some of these scopes, shouldn't the OpenId connect fail?

Comment: It wont fail. As you aware in order to make the above app to work, it has two parts. (1) First you register your app, set the scopes/permissions, get the token using openidconnect/AAD protocols/MSAL libraries (2) Second using this token, you can accessing the protected resources like Microsoft Graph. So check with you exchange/office 365 administrator whether they applied the above policy configured correctly or not. (3) Also you can check whatif the same Graph API call does with Graph explorer or POSTMAN; also worth creating new subscription as well.

Comment: If you see consistent issue then i would suggest you to check with Microsoft Support, they can validate if something is failing at the backend as well.

Comment: I am not sure how to get in contact with Microsoft Support, since their support for MS Graph just refers to stackoverflow.com, and it is not my Office 365 account that is causing problems, but one of my customers.

Comment: It is also odd that I am allowed to read events in the users calendar, but I am not allowed to add a change notification subscription. They both require the permission Calendar.Read.

Comment: @jbiversen - any update this issue? im running into the exact same thing. Even though I receive  the "Calendars.ReadWrite" scope when the user authenticates, its the case for only some users that I receive the same error message.

Comment: @abatis No Microsoft is very silent on this issue.